# Порекомендуйте библиотеку для создания drop-down select меню на RN 0.63

Tags: javascript, react-native, dropdown

[image: Ожидаемый результат]

Порекомендуйте либу которая лучше всего справится с задачей создания подобного drop-down-select меню в react-native. порылся в гугле, не нашел подходящую.
Испробовал:

1. react-native-dropdown-picker
2. Picker который идет из коробки реакта
3. react-native-modal-dropdown
4. и еще какие то либы, уже не помню.

Comment: речь о react-native а не про react.js, в мобильной разработке html теги не используются

Comment: Ой да, не обратил внимание на слово native :(

Comment: Тем не менее «лучше всего» это всё равно слишком расплывчатый критерий

Comment: возможно, прошу прощения за это. я имел ввиду либа которая предоставляет достаточный уровень кастомизации чтобы соответствовать макету

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-dropdown-picker` - она вполне легко кастомизируется в то, что на картинке в вопросе.